# What does the error "unresolved operator InsertIntoStatement LogicalRDD" mean in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When trying to run a fairly simple insert statement in some of my tests, I'm getting the following error:

```
E               pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: unresolved operator 'InsertIntoStatement LogicalRDD [name#0, run_timestamp#1], false, false, false;
E               'InsertIntoStatement LogicalRDD [name#0, run_timestamp#1], false, false, false
E               +- LocalRelation [col1#6, col2#7]
```

What does this mean? I've checked my SQL in a python notebook, and it works just fine.

```
self.spark.sql(f'''
        INSERT INTO migrations
        VALUES ("{job_name}", now())
'''
```

I've tried placing a `breakpoint()` and doing a `describe` on the table name shows it exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In our case, this came about because `migrations` was actually a **view** and not a **table** and thus the insert obviously failed (if only the error msg were better!).

Our test fixtures were incorrectly set up (`createOrReplaceTempView` was being used).